# How Can I Build An React Component Which Consist Multiple Same Form and POST All Data At Single Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, web

I am trying to build an bus-booking-system
I want to build a react component which takes data like name, age, sex and other personal info but for multiple seats.
So Every Seat has a different passenger data and I want to post all data at a single click.
I have tried different ways
Like loop the component no of the seats user is selected times but didn't help as looping a component create a problem to manage state.
and other ways

Example is 
RedBus for booking bus seats
[Image is an example for what I am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcEAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ReduxForm `FieldArrays`. It allows you to have arrays of fields, both an array of one field or of a group of fields.

You should check out the following on how to use it:

- [API Doc](https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/)
- [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/Ww4QG1Wx)

Not tried it with `react-native` but it works fine with `react`.

Comment: Thank You Ladi Aden, I will try and get back to you soon